# how to make use of the API in wpa_ctrl.h by just including these files in my project directory

Tags: openwrt, wpa-supplicant, hostapd

From the official doc referring to wpa_ctrl.c: "External programs can link this file into them" , how to do this?

I have the "hostapd-full" in my openwrt build directory. in which all are fine (Wpa ctrl and wpa cli)

I have to write a sample program which is out side of this "hostapd-full" directory to use wpa_cli/ctrl API.

**Code:**

```
#include "includes.h"
#include <dirent.h>
#include "wpa_ctrl.h"
#include "common.h"

static struct wpa_ctrl *ctrl_conn;
static const char *ctrl_iface_dir = "/var/run/wpa_supplicant";
int main()
{
    ctrl_conn = wpa_ctrl_open(ctrl_iface_dir);
    if (!ctrl_conn){
        printf("Could not get ctrl interface!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

//error:
   Error:
    "/tmp/ccnSzmjE.o: In function `main':
    hostap_wpa_client.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to`wpa_ctrl_open'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    Makefile:8: recipe for target 'logging' failed
    make: *** [logging] Error 1"

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [creating packages](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/packages) in OpenWrt.
You need to create a new package for your program and make the `wpa` package as a dependency for your package and add the library to the `LDFLAGS` in your package Makefile.